# Reading and writing into the XML file

Tags: xml, delphi, delphi-2006, tclientdataset, txmldocument

I need to work on XML files using Delphi.

I want to present the xml data in a DBGrid to the user and save the changes done by user in the XML file.

For example in the below xml (which was presented to the user), if user `changed City of ABC under client` and `added a new customer with NickName as "AAA"` those changes should be reflected in the XML file.

```
<Data LinkID=”0”>
  <Client>
      <Item Name=”ABC” Mobile=”1234” City=”IN” />
      <Item Name=”PQR” Mobile=”5678” City=”IN” />
  </Client>
  <Customer>
    <Item NickName=”XYZ” Phone=”1254” City=”IN” />
    <Item NickName=”MNO” Phone =”41255” City=”IN” />
  </Customer>
</Data>
```

I am working with XMLDocument and ClientDataSet to achieve this but without success.

Can anyone help me in achieving this?

Comment: Bharat, check this question to see how save a `TClientDataset` to a XML file http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3848853/using-delphi7-tclientdataset-is-it-possible-to-have-it-save-its-xml-contents-in/3848892#3848892

Comment: Can you elaborate on which problems or errors are you having? Can you please also add the code you try to use?

Comment: @Vicens: I am getting "Mismatch in datapacket" error

Comment: as far as I know that error may come from a type mismatch in some field. It is hard to say without seeing the code, though.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problems lies with the XML file i am using.

The XML file should be in a specified format which must have `<METADATA> and <ROWDATA>` tags.

I changed the xml to that format.

```
<?xml version="1.0" standalone="yes"?>  
<DATAPACKET Version="2.0">
<METADATA>
<FIELDS>
<FIELD attrname="Name" fieldtype="string" WIDTH="50"/>
<FIELD attrname="Mobile" fieldtype="string" WIDTH="20"/>
<FIELD attrname="City" fieldtype="string" WIDTH="20"/>
</FIELDS><PARAMS CHANGE_LOG="6 1 8"/>
</METADATA>
<ROWDATA>
<ROW Name="ABC" Mobile="1234" City="IN"/>
<ROW Name="PQR" Mobile="5678" City="IN"/>
<ROW Name="AAA" Mobile="7894" City="IN"/>
<ROW Name="MNO" Mobile="4569" City="IN"/>
<ROW Name="ABC" Mobile="45685" City="IN"/>
</ROWDATA>
</DATAPACKET>
```

Next i used 
`ClientDataSet1.LoadFromFile('E:\projects\XML\Sample App with CDS\XmlText.xml');` to read the XML file.

After modifications were done in the grid i used `ClientDataSet1.SaveToFile('E:\projects\XML\Sample App with CDS\XmlText.xml',dfXML);` method to save back to the XML.

There is no need of XMLDocument for this purpose.