# Disable Change_Log in XML file while saving through ClientDataSet

Tags: delphi, delphi-2006

This was continuation to my [previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3987486/reading-and-writing-into-the-xml-file).

I dont want PARAMS CHANGE_LOG data in my XML file while saving the data in ClientDataSet using `ClientDataSet1.SaveToFile()` method.

My code looks like this:

```
ClientDataSet1.Insert;
ClientDataSet1.FieldByName('Name').AsString:= 'AAA';
ClientDataSet1.Append;
ClientDataSet1.SaveToFile('c:\Test.xml',dfxml);
```

How can i achieve this.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Set the LogChanges property of your CLientDAtaSet to False, and it will not bulid the ChangeLog for you...

Comment: Thanks Bob. Can you suggest me which is more effective MergeChangeLog or LogChanges=False

Comment: @Bharat - If you won't make use of the change log, setting 'LogChanges' to false is more effective. When LogChanges is true, data editing becomes slower over time (until changes are merged).

Comment: Setting LogChanges to False is more efficient, since it never needs to save the deltas, and will just apply the changes with every post or insert/delete.

Answer (score 3):

Using `ClientDataSet1.MergeChangeLog` before saving the XML file solves the problem.

Code looks like this:

```
ClientDataSet1.MergeChangeLog;
ClientDataSet1.SaveToFile('c:\Test.xml',dfXML);
```